# install particle js into wordpress or using other method

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How do I implement or install the `particles.js` into wordpress?

http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

I have tried install the particle.js but doesn't work, maybe i miss located some important details.

I also tried the "particles login page" plugin, then try to copy it into the content page, but still no luck.

Any suggestion will be a great help

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get it working in wordpress. I am having the same issues of it not working. I loaded/equeued the particle.js but it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can enqueue a trustworthy CDN if you are not in a position to install it locally.

The following is to be added to your functions.php if you have a standard wordpress architecture.

```
function enqueue_particlejs(){
  wp_enqueue_script('particle-js','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_particlejs');
```

Then you'd need to use their way of actually triggering it on page, which means assigning an id of "particle-js" to one of your dom elements.

```
<div id="particle-js"></div>
```

If you don't have access to the javascript files then you can get away inlining it:

```
<script>
      particlesJS.load('particle-js', '<?= get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/particlejs.json' ?>', function() {
  });
</script>
```

You'll need to create a particlejs.json file somewhere in your wordpress directory and reference it above.

They give one as example or just export one from the website you linked.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do the same. I'm describing how you should do it in the standard way. Upload the particles.js to your active theme folder ( I uploaded it to 'js' folder inside theme director. Open up functions.php in your active theme and insert following code.

```
function load_my_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('muaw-ajax', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/particles.js');    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');
```

Save the changes you made to functions.php, then it should be included to your theme.

Comment: Doesn't work or look like you even tested it. Poor answer